# ionic : npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs, npm-install

I encountered this issue when trying to do `npm install @ionic-native/sqlite`
Does anyone know how to fix it? thank you!

Here's the npm resolution error report:

```
While resolving: devdacticSql@0.0.1
Found: rxjs@7.8.1
node_modules/rxjs
  rxjs@"~7.8.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/core@5.36.0
node_modules/@ionic-native/core
  peer @ionic-native/core@"^5.1.0" from @ionic-native/sqlite@5.36.0
  node_modules/@ionic-native/sqlite
    @ionic-native/sqlite@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I retrued this command with --force, --legacy-peer-depstried and searching online, there are some related answer, but it still does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

the dependencies listed on your package-lock.json are different from the dependencies required in you package.json file.
You can try to change them manually in your package-lock.json (rxjs@"~7.8.0" change with rxjs@"~7.8.1" and so on...) from the root project to solve the dependencies conflicts. Another way is to try to delete the folder node_modules from your root project and the package-lock.json, then you can execute npm install in your terminal